# Save a video when app is closed or terminated

Tags: swift

My app records video and I wanted to stop the video and save it when the app enters background. I found that to run anything during the time the app enters the background you use appdelegate's applicationDidEnterBackground, but it doesn't save the video it only stops the recording.

```
if(vc.recording){
        print("break")
        vc.recordButton.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "start recording"), for: UIControlState.normal)

        vc.recording = false

        self.vc.videoFileOutput.stopRecording()
        let when = DispatchTime.now() + 0.1 // setting .1 second delay
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) { //give slight pause helps media finish and save video correctly
            if UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum((self.vc.filePath?.relativePath)!) {
                UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum((self.vc.filePath?.relativePath)!, nil, nil, nil)
            }else{
                print("error could not save")
            }
        }
        vc.cameraSession.beginConfiguration()
        vc.cameraSession.removeOutput(vc.videoFileOutput)
        vc.cameraSession.commitConfiguration()

    }
```

This is my code and I know that the only line that runs is the self.vc.videoFileOutput.stopRecording(). I do not know why this is the only line that runs, but the main purpose is to run the UISaveVideoAtPathtoSavedPhotosAlbum line. I have tried running this in the applicationWillResign, but it still only stops the recording.

Comment: Just a guess. Consider `viewDidLoadSubviews` versus `viewWillLoadSubviews` - specifically the "did" versus "will". I'm well versed on the *view* lifecycle, but not so much the *app* lifecycle. But after checking `AppDelegate`, the best I see to "app *will* enter background is `applicationWillResignActive`, and I don't think this will work for you. Bottom line, maybe (based on the Apple supplied comments in `applicationDidEnterBackground` you simply cannot do this. There is good news though - show me an app that does what you want and I'll gladly acknowledge I'm completely wrong.

Comment: @dfd the apple camera has it that when the app shuts down the video is automatically saved to your camera roll. So this gives me the belief that this is possible, but I do not know how to do it, so unfortunately, I  am still trying to figure out how apple did it.

Comment: I hope I'm wrong and you find how they do it, but for the second time today I'm commenting about how Apple *owns* the OS and that maybe it takes a *private* API. The first was on a macOS app that wants to know what version of iOS is running on something tethered. Your's? Consider security - seriously, never forget that - and how Apple designed things such that *public* APIs may not allow what you want. As a user (and not knowing the details of your app at all), I *would not* want to find that some app is taking videos *and* saving them without my explicit knowledge. Good luck.

Comment: just to clear up. My app is saving videos when they were left running when the app is closed, so that the person still gets there video even if they forgot to hit stop recording.